# Efficient encoding all the special characters in a string into entities

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have a string like this  "abcd !@&$%^^&*()<>!/". I have list of all the entity codes for characters in a separate string i.e. only encode those characters which are in another string "!=&4....^=9...".  I want to convert all of special characters into their entities except alphanumeric by regex as using loop on characters on by one is too slow.

e.g.  it should show "abc &#4..;&#4.." in other convert words all the special characters on keyboard.

Is there an efficient regex I can write ? I have tried this with loops but it is too slow to look at each character one by one and maintain a list of all special characters entities in other string

There are libraries but they do not convert all of the characters.

The code I wrote

```
// String to be encoded

String sDecoded = "abcd !@#$%^&*();'m,";
// Special character entity list to put instead to special character. It is     tokenized on cross and divide symbol as it cannot be entered by user on keyboard

String specialCharacters = "&÷$amp;×–÷&ndash;"


// Check the input
if (sDecoded == null || sDecoded.trim ().length () == 0)
  return (sDecoded);

// Use StringTokenizer which is faster than split method
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(specialCharacters, "×");
String[] reg = null;
String[] charactersArray = sDecoded.split("");
String sEncoded = "";

// now loop on it and in each iteration, we will be getting a decodedCharacter:EncodedEntity pair 


for(int i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++)
{   
    st = new StringTokenizer(specialCharacters, "×");


    while(st.hasMoreElements())
    {
        reg = st.nextElement().toString().split("÷");

         // This is an error, the character should not be blank ever because it will be character that we will encode
         if(StringUtils.isBlank(reg[0]))
            return sDecoded;

        String c = charactersArray[i];


        if(c.equalsIgnoreCase(reg[0]))
        {
            sEncoded = sEncoded + c.replace(reg[0], reg[1]);
            break;
        }

        if(st.countTokens() == 0)
            sEncoded = sEncoded + c.toString();

 }

}

    return (sEncoded);
```

Comment: If doing this character by character is slow, doing with regex is going to be slower. Regex is not a magic wand - it scans strings and backtracks when they don't match. How about showing what you attempted exactly, and we'll perhaps be able to help you improve it.

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't compile - there is a problem in the string literal.

Comment: Why are you using the complicated `specialCharacters` string? Why not use a proper `Map` which will be much faster to search?

Comment: Actually I won't use String to hold them. It is just example. The characters will be held outside code in configuration file which we can change without changing code. so, whatever characters we want to add, we add in that .ini file in a tokenized string way and read from there.

Comment: Great, I'm asking about the form that it will take inside the Java program. After all, you are not considering reading the `ini` file again and again in your program - you will load it once into a data structure. That data structure should not be a complicated string as you created, but rather, a map.

Comment: So, to do it faster, I will first read the special characters list from .ini file, then convert it into map in code and then perform for loop on each character of the string to be converted ?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I would have marked this as answer if it was not a comment. Thanks for that! I used a static block map to initialize the special characters which has made it very fast and due to static block map, it does not initialize each time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what definition of "efficient" you are using, but there's the "don't reinvent the wheel" efficiency of using a simple call to Apache commons-text [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) utility class:

```
String encoded = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(str);
```

or

```
String encoded = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(str);
```

and a variety of other similar methods, depending on which exact encoding you want.

---

Note: This class was originally in the commons-lang3 library, but was deprecated there and moved to the commons-text library.

Comment: It does not convert every character like !@#$%^^&*()_ -

Comment: Can we use regex ?

Comment: @aiden no. Regex matches, it doesn't transform. I might be able to provide an efficient algorithm, but please tell me exactly how you want the encoding to be done, eg to encode `'!'` you specified `&#4..;`. Is that literally what you want? If not, exactly what do you want? `'!'` is decimal `33`, do you want octal `041`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I just put ... as stacktrace removes any special entities. So, actually I want to convert & to &amp; and , to &#44 and ' to &#39. The reason is when these special characters are used my XSLT transformer removes them e.g. if Dash is used in a string "abcd - def" it gives output as "". So, only way is to encode the spcial characters.

Comment: So, I put all the special characters in tokenized separated string outside the in a configuration file (so that I do not have to change code), and used  token character which a person can never type i.e.  ,÷&#44;×&÷&amp. Now code will pick special charcter , before token ÷ and it knows everything after it and before × is the encoded entity, so it replaces it in a while loop.

Comment: I used a static block and initialized a map in it with all the character entities list and instead of loops on these entities I just used Map containKey function to see if I have a character to encode or not.

Comment: @3xCh1_23 link updated from common-lang3 to common-text. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is quite slow and inefficient. Maybe it looks elegant nowadays to use regex like a silver bullet for everything, but it is definitely not for this task. I see you are also using tokenizer which is also slow.Also loop inside a loop will degrade performance.

I would recomment using an iterative way with string builder which will produce blazing fast results, you will try for yourself. For each special character make an 'if' statement. Even if it looks too much code it will be very fast. Test yourself.
Try this :

```
class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(escapeSpecials("abc &"));
    }

    public static String escapeSpecials(String origin) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        char[] chars = origin.toCharArray();
        for (char c : chars) {
            if (c == '&') {
                result.append("&amp;");
            } else if (c == '\u2013') {
                result.append("&ndash;");
            } else {
                // not a special character
                result.append(c);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```